# R script to export in batches

Tags: r

I posted a similar question before but my question has now changed so thought I'd post again. I have a data table with two columns; number and value, as follows;

```
number  value
1   test1
1   test2
1   test3
2   test4
2   test5
3   test6
3   test7
3   test8
4   test9
5   test10
6   test11
7   test12
8   test13
9   test14
10  test15
11  test16
12  test17
13  test18
14  test19
15  test20
16  test21
17  test22
18  test23
19  test24
20  test25
21  test26
22  test27
23  test28
```

I would like to export the data table as multiple .txt files. The first text file should contain a subset of the entire data table where number is between 1-20. The second text file should contain a subset of the data where the number is between 21-40, the third where the number is between 41-60 and so on. The data table is dynamic, so the number of .txt files exported will vary.

Furthermore, in all .txt files, the 'number' must be between 1-20. So if the number is 21, it must be renamed to 1, if the number is 22, it must be renamed to 2, etc.

Is anybody able to help? In the example above, there should be 2 .txt files, the first with 25 rows and the second with 3 rows, and the second .txt file containing numbers 21,22,23 renamed to 1,2,3.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Each step should not be difficult - maybe you can share where you got stuck.

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure how to do this, I'm new to R. I don't know how to separate the data tables into batches of 20 whilst the table is dynamic

Comment: How do you get 25 and 3 rows out of a dataset with 23 rows by splitting to batches of 20? .. ah I see, my bad - the number is not a row number:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would split your data frame into chunks of 20 rows using `split()`. This function will split your data frame according to some criterion. In your case, this criterion could be something like: "what is the outcome of the row number divided by 20 (rounded to up/down to an integer)?". According to this rule, the input data will be split.

```
nrows <- 1:nrow(df)
df    <- split(df, floor(nrows/20))
```

---

**Edit**: If you want to split according to the value in `df$number`, you should use `df <- split(df, floor((df$number-1)/20))`

---

Secondly, you must somehow transform deduct multiples of 20 for all number higher than 20. I would have used modulo `%% 20`, but that also transform 20 to zero.

```
ready_for_export <- lapply(df, function(x){
                       x$number <- (x$number - floor((x$number-1)/20)*20)
                       return(x)})
```

Finally, save the element in the list `ready_for_export` in separate txt documents. I'd use a `for`-loop for this:

```
for(i in seq_along(ready_for_export)){
   write.table(ready_for_export[[i]], paste0("test", i, ".txt"))
}
```

There are probably packages out there, that will make it look nicer and perform faster, however, I like to stick with base `R` as much as possible.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help. My problem is not that they need to be split into rows of 20 but rather batches where the value in the 'number' column is between 1-20, 21-40 etc.

Comment: @Ash_23S, I edited the answer. It's almost the same as before, just with a different version of the `split()` call

Comment: thanks very much, this looks great! only 1 problem - the first txt file which has been exported contains 'number' column values of 1-19, rather than 1-20. is there a way to change this?

Comment: Yes, just change the split-call to `split(df, floor((df$number-1)/20))`. Note the `-1` after `df$number`

Comment: It should be 2 text files, based on the data you posted.. Is your question answered or not? I made an edit to avoid that the number 20 is replaced with a 0.

Answer (score 1):

The `tidyverse` allows you to write a solution that is more .. tidy;)

Say your data is in variable `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(set = plyr::round_any(number - 1, 20, floor) %>% as.factor %>% as.numeric) %>% 
  group_by(set) %>%
  mutate(set_num = number %>% as.factor %>% as.numeric) %>%
  ungroup ->
  df_prep

df_prep$set %>%
  unique %>%
  walk(~ write_tsv(df_prep %>% 
                     filter(set == .x) %>%
                     select(number = set_num,
                            value),
                   paste0("file-", .x, ".tsv")))
```

Where the `as.factor %>% as.numeric` trick assigns new unique numeric ids to distinct values of the column. The right assignmnent `->` is a bit unusual, but makes the `magrittr` pipeline flow nicely.

Comment: thanks very much for your help. I think I need to stick to a base R solution though.